# How should we implement access gateway authentication in ASP.NET 5 MVC6?

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core-mvc

we're strugling with an existing access gateway, that effectively does user authentication. When a user is authenticated the access gateway sets a couple of request headers and passes the request to our underlying ASPNET5 MVC6 web application. Using these values, which are no encrypted values, we can derive a couple of things, including the userid of the person that is logged in ... we do not get a password or some fancy token.

Can anyone tell us what is the clean/correct MVC6 way to implement access gateway authentication? We've seen several authentication solutions, but either it expected a single token or it expected a username + password.

Answer (score 0):

Well actually you're in luck - since you don't have to deal with authorization yourself. All you need is to do is notify .NET infrastructure about it. Easiest way is to add your own `IAuthenticationFilter`

This example assumes you must have both "X-FIRST-NAME" and "X-LAST-NAME" present in request as http-headers in order be treated as authenticated user.

```
public class CustomHostAuthenticationFilter : IAuthenticationFilter
{
    public bool AllowMultiple { get { return true; } }

    public Task AuthenticateAsync(HttpAuthenticationContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        }

        var request = context.Request;
        if (request == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Request must not be null.", nameof(context));
        }

        if (request.Headers != null)
        {
            string firstName = null;
            IEnumerable<string> values;
            if (request.Headers.TryGetValues("X-FIRST-NAME", out values) && values.Any())
            {
                firstName = values.First();
            }

            string lastName = null;
            if (request.Headers.TryGetValues("X-LAST-NAME", out values) && values.Any())
            {
                lastName = values.First();
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(firstName) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(lastName))
            { 
                var identity = new ClaimsIdentity("JWT");
                identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, firstName + " " + lastName));
                var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
                context.Principal = principal;
            }
        }

        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }

    public Task ChallengeAsync(HttpAuthenticationChallengeContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}
```

And add the filter to a pipeline.

```
services.ConfigureMvc(options =>
{
  options.Filters.Add(new CustomHostAuthenticationFilter());
}
```

Comment: This actually looks very good, I will try this tomorrow ... it looks like it might work perfectly well. Thanks. Just one thing, isn't it called IAuthorizationFilter nowadays?